# Argo WorkflowTemplate free form input parameters

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, freeform

Picked up as a reference: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/workflow-template/templates.yaml#L11

Is it possible to pass input parameters as key-value pair collection in `WorkflowTemplate` ? The reason I am asking is that it seems like every time we need to introduce a field, we have to change the template and define name of the field in there. So looking for a free form support in Argo WorkflowTemplate input parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argo Workflows (and WorkflowTemplates) [do not currently support dictionary-like input parameters](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/2077).

There are work-arounds. For example, you could pass your inputs as a JSON-encoded string. Or (if the inputs are particularly large), you could pass an artifact.

Comment: I found something similar here https://argoproj.github.io/argo/examples/#loops . When you say JSON-encoded string, are you referring to this?

Comment: I guess I should have said, "string-encoded JSON" (or any string-formatted data structure you prefer). The loop feature does indeed know how to loop over a string-encoded JSON list. But I don't think that gives you the flexibility you need, since you want all the parameters available at once rather than as individual items in a loop.

Comment: yes I need to parse all parameters at once. Do we have any example of enumerating and parsing a sample string?

Comment: I can find you examples of looping over stringified-JSON, but I don't think that's what you want. Your container can do the JSON parsing/parameterization with something like jq or your favorite language's JSON parser.

Comment: Here's a light example of using jq to parse an input parameter: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/d2c03f67c2fd45ff54c04db706c9ebf252fca6f2/test/e2e/functional/json-argument.yaml